# How to store years of type Calendar into an array?

Tags: java, android, arrays, for-loop, calendar

I'm trying to create an array and populate it with currentYear+1 to max of 15 Calendar [] years = {2016, 2017, 2018, 2019,.......2031} and I want to display it in a numberpicker. So far I was able to get the currentYear and add 1 year to it but I'm facing a problem when I try to store the results into an array in a for loop.

my code so far

```
Calendar cal;
Calendar [] years = new Calendar[15];
public Calendar [] getYears(){


    cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    //cal.add(Calendar.YEAR, 1);
    for(int i = 1; i < years.length; i ++){

        Calendar temp = cal.add(Calendar.YEAR, 1);
        years [i] = temp ;

    }


    return years;
}
```

Comment: What problem are you facing?

Comment: when I try to populate the array with temp I get an error "incompatible types required java.util.Calendar found void"

Comment: *I get an error "incompatible types required java.util.Calendar found void"* ... [It is obvious ...](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#add(int,%20int)) does add return Calendar? ... if you need years only why you have Calendar array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, if the array holds `15` years then it would be from `2016` until `2030`, not `31`.

Secondly if you just add the cal field to all of the places of the `array years` then you will have 15 references pointing to the exact same `Object`. What you want to do is create cloned objects and point to them, which you can do with the [clone()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#clone()) method.

So try changing the method to something like:

```
public Calendar[] getYears() {
    cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    for (int index = 0; index < years.length;) {
        years[index++] = (Calendar) cal.clone();
        cal.add(Calendar.YEAR, 1);
    }
    return years;
}
```

But if all you want is to store the years I would recommend changing your code to something like:

```
Calendar cal;
int[] years = new int[15];

public int[] getYears() {
    cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    int year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    for (int index = 0; index < years.length;) {
        years[index++] = year + index;
    }
    return years;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. How would I print or Log the results of the array?

Comment: @khalidalqahtani Create a method that returns a string version of the array. i.e :`public String toString(){ StringBuilder string = new StringBuilder();for(int year: years){string.append(year + ", ");}return string.toString();}`.